# Android studio location

Tags: android, geolocation

Iv made a location app, when I open it it opens on a map of the world and I have to hit the target icon thing in the top right hand corner for it to zoom into user location, how do I make it automatically zoom to user location when app is opened?

Answer (score 1):

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false));
        if (location != null) {

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(d.getLatitude(), d.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())) // Sets
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // center
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // map
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // location
                                                                            // user
                    .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            // change marker you


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CameraPosition` to show users location.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder ()
                    .target (curentpoint).zoom (10f).tilt (70).build ();
```

Where `target` is current `LatLog` getting from either `gps` or `network`. 
`zoom` will Zoom map to 10. tilt will change map's angle.

after that use `animateCamera` method to add cameraposition.

```
mGoogleMap.animateCamera (CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition (cameraPosition));
```

I hope this is what you want.